# Error : Can't set header after it has been sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, stripe-payments

I'm a getting the 'Can't set headers after they are sent' error when running a project using Stripe API on Heroku. From a lot of searching around, I think it's do to with not calling `return;` before a `send()` or a `render()` but i've given that a try and am not sure where it's meant to go.

My code:

```
app.post('/charge', (req, res) => {
  const amount = 999;

  const plan = stripe.plans.create({
    currency: 'gbp',
    interval: 'month',
    name: 'XXXX',
    amount: 999
  });

  stripe.customers.create({
    email: req.body.stripeEmail,
    source: req.body.stripeToken
  })
  .then(customer => stripe.charges.create({
    amount,
    description: 'XXXX',
    currency: 'gbp',
    customer: customer.id
  }, function(err, subscription){
    if(err){
      res.send({
        success: false,
        message: 'Error'
      });
    } else {
      const {id} = customer;
      stripe.subscriptions.create({
        customer: id,
        items: [
          {
            plan: 'XXXXX'
          }
        ]
      }, function(err,subscription){
        if(err){
          res.send({
            success: false,
            message: 'Error'
          });
        } else {
          res.send({
            success: true,
            message: 'success'
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }))
  .then(charge => res.render('success'));
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The `error` is likely due to trying to `res.render()` after firing `res.send()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This error comes when you try to set headers after you have sent the response i.e res.send() two times for the same request.

In your code, I guess after one error block's res.send(), second error block is getting executed.

Please try to use only promise or only callbacks if possible, it's easy to debug.

You can refine your code like this -

```
 stripe.customers.create(ob1)
     .then(res1 => {
         if(res1){
             return stripe.charges.create(ob2)
         }
     })
     .then(res2 => {
         if(res2){
             return stripe.operation3(ob3)
         }
     })
     .then(res3 => {
         if(res3){
             // Success response
         }
     })
     .catch(err => {
         // Send error message accordingly
     });
```

You can also create else for each if for more flex error handling, but then handle other blocks carefully.

Comment: Thanks, works fine now! It makes a lot more sense when you write it out like that.